# Moment locale not working in build version but working in local dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, momentjs

> I have an application using **Next.js** where i need to show **Bengali** date instead of **English**. But, during `dev: next dev` it's working as expected. But after `build:next build` it's not working as expected. In production optimised version, I see that it's showing in English e.g. `২০ জানুয়ারি, রবিবার` this to `20 January, Sunday`.

**What's wrong with my code?**

```
import { DateIcon } from "../../../utils/svgImages/svgImage";
import BeguniButton from "../../../components/Buttons/BeguniButton";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { STUDENT_SPECIFIC_LESSONS_QUERY } from "../../../api/liveClass";
import moment from "moment"; // <-- You see?
import "moment/locale/bn"; // <-- You see?
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Empty, Skeleton } from "antd";
import SectionError from "../../../components/Error/Section";
import { classTypeDic } from "../../../lib/utils/constants";
import LiveClassDetails from "./LiveClassDetails";

const sliderSettings = {
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 200,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  initialSlide: 0,
  className: "general-slider",
};

const TodayClass = ({
  router,
  lessonId,
  contentId,
  subName,
  subColor,
  classType,
  status,
  title,
  chapterName,
  startTime,
  endTime,
  date,
}) => {
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  const joinLiveClass = () =>
    router.push(
      `/student/live-class/${contentId}?lesson_id=${lessonId}&programType=AcademicProgramLiveClassObject`
    );
  const seeDetails = () => setShowDetails(!showDetails);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col px-4 py-5 border border-OutlineLightBlue rounded-lg md:rounded-10">
        <div className="flex gap-x-2.5 items-center">
          <div
            className="font-balo font-medium text-xs md:text-14px md:leading-6"
            style={{ color: subColor }}
          >
            {subName}
          </div>
          <div className="w-1 md:w-1.5 h-1 md:h-1.5 bg-OutlineLightBlue rounded-full" />
          <div className="font-balo font-medium text-xs md:text-14px md:leading-6 text-Body">
            {classType} ক্লাস
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-3 md:mt-2 font-balo font-semibold text-base md:text-lg text-Body">
          {title}
        </div>
        <div className="mt-0 md:mt-2 font-balo font-medium text-14px leading-6 md:text-base text-Body">
          {chapterName}
        </div>
        {status === `ongoing` ? (
          <div className="mt-2.5 md:mt-1.5 mb-5 md:mb-4 flex gap-x-2 md:gap-x-2.5 items-center">
            <div className="w-2 md:w-2.5 h-2 md:h-2.5 bg-Semantic rounded-full" />
            <div className="font-balo font-medium text-xs text-Semantic md:text-14px leading-6">
              তোমার ক্লাস শুরু হয়ে গেছে
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="mt-2.5 md:mt-1.5 mb-5 md:mb-4 flex gap-x-2 items-center text-xs font-balo font-medium md:text-14px leading-6 text-Body2">
            <DateIcon />
            <div className="font-grotesk font-normal">{date}</div>
            <div>|</div>
            <div>
              {startTime} - {endTime}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        <BeguniButton
          onClick={status === `ongoing` ? joinLiveClass : seeDetails}
          icon={false}
        >
          {status === `ongoing` ? `এখনই জয়েন করো` : `বিস্তারিত দেখো`}
        </BeguniButton>
      </div>
      <LiveClassDetails
        id={contentId}
        isOpen={showDetails}
        toggle={seeDetails}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const TodayClasses = ({ router, enrolledProgramId }) => {
  const [stdSpecificLessons, setStdSpecificLessons] = useState([]);
  const startDate = moment().locale("en").format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // <-- You see?
  const endDate = moment().locale("en").format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // <-- You see?

  const [fetchStudentSpecificLessons, { loading, error }] = useLazyQuery(
    STUDENT_SPECIFIC_LESSONS_QUERY,
    {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enrolledProgramId) {
      fetchStudentSpecificLessons({
        variables: {
          program_id: enrolledProgramId,
          start_date: startDate,
          end_date: endDate,
          content_type: "LiveClass",
        },
        onCompleted: (response) => {
          const {
            studentSpecificLessons: { data },
          } = response;

          if (data?.length) {
            const formattedArray = data
              .filter((item) => {
                return moment
                  .utc(item.live_class.end_time)
                  .local(true) // <-- You see?
                  .isAfter(moment.utc());
              })
              .map((item) => {
                const subColor = `#${item.color_code.split(",")[0]}`;
                let status;
                const startTime = moment
                  .utc(item.live_class.start_time)
                  .local(true); // <-- You see?
                const endTime = moment
                  .utc(item.live_class.end_time)
                  .local(true); // <-- You see?
                const currentTime = moment.utc();
                if (currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime)) {
                  status = "ongoing";
                } else if (startTime.diff(currentTime, "minutes") > 10) {
                  status = "upcoming";
                } else {
                  status = "ongoing";
                }

                return {
                  lessonId: item.id,
                  contentId: item.content_id,
                  subName: item.live_class.subject_name,
                  subColor: subColor,
                  classType: classTypeDic[item.live_class.type],
                  status: status,
                  title: item.title,
                  chapterName: item.live_class.chapter_name,
                  startTime: moment
                    .utc(item.live_class.start_time)
                    .local(true) // <-- You see?
                    .format("h.mm a"),
                  endTime: moment
                    .utc(item.live_class.end_time)
                    .local(true) // <-- You see?
                    .format("h.mm a"),
                  date: moment
                    .utc(item.live_class.start_time)
                    .local(true) // <-- You see?
                    .format("D MMM, dddd"),
                };
              });

            setStdSpecificLessons(formattedArray);
          }
        },
        onError: (err) => console.log(err),
      });
    }
  }, [enrolledProgramId, startDate, endDate, fetchStudentSpecificLessons]);

  if (loading) return <Skeleton active />;
  if (error) return <SectionError />;
  if (stdSpecificLessons.length === 0) return <Empty />;

  return (
    <>
      <section className="block lg:hidden">
        <Slider {...sliderSettings}>
          {stdSpecificLessons?.map((item) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
            return <TodayClass router={router} {...item} />;
          })}
        </Slider>
      </section>
      <section className="hidden lg:grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
        {stdSpecificLessons?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-span-6 2xl:col-span-4" key={Math.random()}>
              <TodayClass router={router} {...item} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default TodayClasses;
```

---

You can see in the above code that for API call i'm using `en` & for showing the result using in `bn`. By the way, i've tried `moment.locale('bn')` outside the main component but that also doesn't work.

---

My `packages.json` looks like below:

```
{
  "name": "landingpage-shikho",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 4001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "fix": "yarn lint --fix",
    "pre-commit": "yarn lint --fix && git add -A ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.12",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.3",
    "@phuocng/react-pdf-viewer": "^1.7.0",
    "antd": "^5.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cloudinary-core": "^2.11.4",
    "constate": "^3.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.5.207",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.35.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hls-player": "^3.0.7",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.2",
    "react-player": "^2.11.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-select": "^4.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.4.0",
    "react-use-downloader": "^1.2.1",
    "recharts": "2.1.12",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.14",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Locale is not the same as [local](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/). If you want to switch between locales, I'd suggest import both and set `moment.locale('en')` or `moment.locale('br')` accordingly. Take a look at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browserify/

Comment: Does your system have **bengali** locale configured? On production you will not have that locale. So in your code you need to specify bengali locale to mement instead of using system locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locale is not the same as [local](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/).
If you want to switch between locales, I'd suggest import both and set `moment.locale('en')` or `moment.locale('br')` accordingly. Take a look at momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browserify